# PHP Connect elastic beanstalk to MongoDB ec2

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an elastic beanstalk web server set up for my website, and have also created an ec2 server and installed mongodb on it so that I can use it as the database for my website. I know the database works, and I can add documents and access them from ec2. However, I wasn't sure how to connect to the mongodb server through PHP from another site (the one I created with elastic beanstalk).

Thank you for any help. I am pretty new with AWS, so if this is a poor website setup, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try under your instance for the EB> security and groups>click on your database instance and edit the inbound rules. Allow SSH/HTTPS/HTTP from your EB's instance.